# Printing a formatted list (Python)

Tags: python

How can I print a list and make a new line after each element?
For instance, 
I want this list:  [1, 2, 3]

to be formatted so that when I run print(list) the output is:

[

'1'

'2'

'3'

]

how do i achieve this?

Comment: You need to make an attempt at solving the question (and include it in your post) rather than asking code to specification. Also you can use three backticks to format code or things that are layout sensitive like your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using json module you can dump the list(any json object) with indentation.

```
import json

print(json.dumps(["1", "2", "3"], indent=1))
```

Output:

```
[
 "1",
 "2",
 "3"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def special_print(my_list):
    print('[')
    for elem in my_list:
        print(f"'{elem}'")
    print(']')
```

Test case:

```
>>> special_print([1, 2, 3])
[
'1'
'2'
'3'
]
```

Comment: i was wondering if I could manipulate the list itself so that I wouldnt have to create a whole function to do the trick. is there a way where I can format the list so when i simply print(list), i get my desired output?

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(l):
    return '[\n'+'\n'.join([str(i) for i in l])+'\n]'
```

Answer (score 0):

In two lines, no function:

```py
l = [1, 2, 3]

s = "'{}'\n" * len(l)
print("[\n{}]".format(s.format(*l)))

# [
# '1'
# '2'
# '3'
# ]
```

---

If you just want to use a normal `print` you can subclass `UserList`, like so:

```py
from collections import UserList
class my_list(UserList):
    def __repr__(self):
        s = "'{}'\n" * len(self)
        return "[\n{}]".format(s.format(*self))
    def __str__(self):
        s = "'{}'\n" * len(self)
        return "[\n{}]".format(s.format(*self))

print(my_list([1, 2, 3]))
# [
# '1'
# '2'
# '3'
# ]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`pprint` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) for pretty printing:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> L = [1, 2, 3]
>>> pprint(L, width=1)

[1,
 2,
 3]
```

If you need quotes around each integer, project them first to strings:

```
>>> S = [str(item) for item in L]
>>> S
['1', '2', '3']
>>> pprint(S, width=1)


['1',
 '2',
 '3']
```

Comment: is there a way to print the elements the line after the initial bracket?

Comment: @AllenLee I don't think `pprint` provides such flexibility.

Comment: @AllenLee If that is really important I would rather create my own function to print it the way I need similar to what the other answers suggest.